# Show the grandmother/father of the childpage

Tags: child-pages

I have a little problem.

This is my page structure:

```
Ancestor 
   Parent 
     Child 1 
       Child 2 
         Child 3 
            Child 4
```

What i try to do is when i'm on Child 4 i want to show Child 2.

And when i'm on Child 2 i want to show Parent.

But i can't figure out how to do this.
The code that i use is this:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul id="child-menu">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at `get_ancestors()` to get the top level parent of a page. Just a note, for reliability, use `get_queried_object()` (*or even better `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()`*) to get the current post/page object on singular pages, `$post` can be quite unreliable

You can try the following in your shortcode:

```
$post = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object();
// Make sure the current page is not top level
if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent ) {
    $parent = $post->ID;
} else {
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $post->ID, $post->post_type );
    $parent    = end( $ancestors );
}
```

`$parent` will now always hold the top level parent of any given page

### EDIT - from comments

If you need to get the page two levels higher than the current one, you can still use the same approach, but insted of using the last ID from `get_ancestors (*which is the top level parent*), we need to adjust this to get the second entry

Lets modify the code above slightly

```
$post = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object();
// Make sure the current page is not top level
if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent ) {
    $parent = $post->ID;
} else {
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $post->ID, $post->post_type );
    // Check if $ancestors have at least two key/value pairs
    if ( 1 == count( $ancestors ) ) {
        $parent = $post->post_parent;
    } esle {
        $parent = $ancestors[1]; // Gets the parent two levels higher
    }
}
```

### LAST EDIT - full code

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() 
{
    // Define our $string variable
    $string = '';

    // Make sure this is a page
    if ( !is_page() )
        return $string;

    $post = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object();
    // Make sure the current page is not top level
    if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent ) {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $post->ID, $post->post_type );
        // Check if $ancestors have at least two key/value pairs
        if ( 1 == count( $ancestors ) ) {
            $parent = $post->post_parent;
        } else {
            $parent = $ancestors[1]; // Gets the parent two levels higher
        }
    }  

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $parent . '&echo=0' );

    $string .= '<ul id="child-menu">' . $childpages . '</ul>';

    return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```

Comment: My pleasure. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: wel this is something but not it.

this my page structure:

Ancestor
      Parent
          Child 1
            Child 2
              Child 3
                Child 4

What i try to do is when i'm on Child 4 i want to show Child 2.

and when i'm on Child 2 i want to show Parent.

But i can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: That is info that you should have posted **inside your question**. Please be sure to add such relevant code in your question the first time so that we do not waste our time answering irrelevant stuff

Comment: thanks but i think i'm doing something wrong.

Your edit is now placed in:

`function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() {
------Your Code-------
}
add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i hate to say it but i get a blank page.

For some reason it breaks the `functions.php` file i think

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo (*which happens if one code from a mobile device ;-)*). Fixed it

Comment: This is super.

But now i'm looking (without having to copy the whole code) that when the child page has child pages of it's own that it wil not show those child pages but still the parrent page 2 levels up.

i played with it but in my opinion i have to copy the whole code change the level setting and give a different shortcode name.

Comment: Please ask this as a new question with this new requirement. This is out of scope of this question. What was asked in the question was solved by my answer. What you are asking now is completely different which requires a rewrite of the shortcode itself, and not my code from my answer ;-)

Comment: Could you maby help me further?

[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219499/do-not-show-childpages-of-childpages)

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what your question is, mainly because you're talking about parents and childs but this will never show the parent of a page let alone the grandparent.

I've commented your code down here to show you what exactly what is happenign in the code.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() { 

    // Get the current WP Post object
    global $post;

    /**
     * If post_type of current WP Post object is 'page'
     * and the post_parent in the WP Post object is set
     */
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        /**
         * Get all wordpress pages that are a child of this pages parent.
         * In other words get THIS page and all it's siblings
         */
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    /**
     * If this page doesn't have a parent
     */
    else
        /**
         * Get all wordpress pages that are a child of this page
         */
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

    if ( $childpages ) {

        $string = '<ul id="child-menu">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```

What I'm guessing is that you simply want a list with alle pages that are "connected" by being a (grand)parent, (grand)child, or sibling.
This function returns a string that contains all of that no matter which of the siblings you're on.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() {

    // Get the current WP Post object
    global $post;

    if ( is_page() ) {

        /**
         * Get 'first' parent, the highest ranking post parent which is the ancestor of all.
         * @var array
         */
        $ancestor = array_reverse( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) );
        // If there is no ancestor, set ancestor to this page.
        if ( empty( $ancestor ) ) {
            $ancestor_id = $post->ID;
        }
        else {
            $ancestor_id = $ancestor[0];
        }

        // Get childpages from ancestor
        $pages = wp_list_pages( array(
            'child_of'  => $ancestor_id,
            'title_li'  => '',
            'echo'      => 0
        ) );

        $string = '<ul id="child-menu">';
        // Ancestor is not included in the $pages so add this manually
        $string .= '<li class="ancestor"><a href="' . get_the_permalink( $ancestor_id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $ancestor_id ) . '</a></li>';
        $string .= '<ul class="children">';
        $string .= $pages;
        $string .= '</ul>';
        $string .= '</ul>';

        return $string;
    }
}
add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```